# Proving that the power series for the cosine function is greater than zero, for $x$ in $[0, \pi/2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, proof-writing, taylor-expansion

> I'm trying to prove the cosine power series
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} \;>\;0$$ 
>   for all $x \in [0, \pi/2)$. Here, $\pi$ is defined as the smallest positive real such that $\cos\frac{\pi}{2} = 0$.

My initial thoughts for an attempt at a solution:

Showing that the series achieves an absolute maximum and minimum at its endpoints, respectfully, and that both of these are positive. Thus by the intermediate value theorem, all points between must also be greater than zero.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to formally write this as a proof, however.

Comment: To solve this question, the way you define $\pi$ is important.

Comment: Right. Forgot to metion that we have defined $pi$ as the smallest positive real number such that cos($pi$/2) = 0.

Comment: Did you prove that the $\cos$ function is continuous?

Comment: Well since series converges by the absolute series convergence test, the series would be continuous, correct?

Comment: If $\pi/2$ is defined as the smallest positive zero of $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=f(x)$ there is nothing to prove: such function is continuous and (positive where positive).

Comment: The interesting question is to prove that the smallest positive zero of $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ is half the area of the unit circle.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $f(x)= \cos x$. You have $f(0)=1$. As $f$ is continuous (converging power series are continuous), $f$ is strictly positive around $0$.

You can then conclude with $\pi$ definition.

Comment: Which "*$\pi$ definition*"? The area of the unit circle is not immediately related to the first positive root of $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio See the question I ask to the OP and his answer. He defines $\pi$ as the smallest positive integer such that $\cos \pi/2 =0$.

Comment: Positive real and not positive integer!

Answer (score 1):

$\cos x$, defined as its Maclaurin series, is an entire solution of the differential equation $f''(x)+f(x)=0$, $f(0)=1$, $f'(0)=1$. $\cos x$ is even and concave where positive, and we may denote with $\alpha$ the smallest positive zero of $\cos x$. The problem boils down to showing that $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Now, by denoting through $\sin x$ the opposite of the derivative of $\cos x$, we have that $f''+f=0$ implies that $f^2+f'^2$ is constant, in particular equal to one (Pythagorean theorem, $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$). Since $\cos x$ is decreasing on $(0,\alpha)$ and the Pythagorean theorem plus the chain rule imply that the derivative of the inverse function of $\cos x$ is $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, we have
$$ \alpha = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$
Integration by parts relates $\alpha$ with the area of the unit circle:
$$ \alpha = 2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2} $$
and we are done: the series defining $\cos x$ is positive on $[0,\alpha)=\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.
As a side-effect, we have the hypergeometric identities
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{(2n+1)4^n},\qquad \frac{\pi}{2}=2-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n(n+1)(2n+3)}$$
provided by the Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2}$.
 The latter is faster-convergent, of course.

Answer (score 0):

We can use geometry to show $\cos(x)$ is $C^{(\infty)}.$ Then we can use Lagrange Remainder Theorem to show the series equals the cosine function on all $\mathbb{R}$. Then we automatically get that the series is positive whenever $\cos(x)$ is positive.

Comment: If $\cos x$ is *defined* as its Maclaurin series, there is no *geometry* we may invoke unless we prove it.

Comment: Then call the geometric version of $\cos(x)$ banana and use the same argument to show that $\text{banana}(x)=\cos(x).$ The statement I gave was how to show the geometric definition equals the series. That's the crux, it doesn't matter what you call them.

Comment: *That's the crux* - I do not agree, since you do not need the geometric version of $\cos x$ to relate its first positive zero with the area of the circle. Yours (properly worded) is just one way.

Comment: Well, I meant the crux of my argument. Sorry if it seemed I meant every argument. Also, I do think my statement is properly worded, it's just missing details.

Answer (score 0):

A famous diagram-based argument shows any acute $x$ satisfies $0\le\sin x\le x$. Alternate use of $\cos x=1-\int_0^x\sin t dt,\,\sin x=\int_0^x\cos t dt$ allows us to prove by induction that $c_{2n+1}\le\cos x\le c_{2n}$ with $c_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-x^2)^k}{(2k)!}$, and a similar result for $\sin x$. Since the ratio test implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n$ is finite for any acute $x$, by the squeeze theorem this limit is $\cos x\ge 0$.

Comment: You are (more or less) starting by assuming the thesis, i.e. that $$ 0 \leq \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\leq x$$ holds for any $x\in[0,\pi/2]$. We need to *prove* the geometric properties of $\cos x$ or $\sin x$ if they are just defined through their Maclaurin series.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No, I'm defining the trigonometric functions from geometry, and deducing their range on acute angles from geometry, and proving what the series converges to from geometry.

Comment: Then how do you relate $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ with the geometric definition of $\cos x$? I agree that if we show $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\cos x\text{ defined by geometry}$$ we have nothing to do more.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think I spelled it out pretty well.